# Can I use "over to John" when I want to say "now it is John's turn to speak"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

During our conference calls, I keep using the phrase "..and now I give/yield the floor to.." but that sounds to me a bit "formal". I know I could also say "...so now I hand you over to John".
Could I just say "and now, over to John"?

What other alternatives would be acceptable in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, in an online meeting, brevity is best.

"Over to John" is perfectly adequate in any such meeting. It's standard language which will be encountered on TV.

If your company's culture is one which frowns upon informality, then maybe you have a problem -- but I can't think of any reasons why "Over to John" can be considered *too* casual and informal.